# How delete folder named "build" in all subfolders?

Tags: dired, files, directories

Emacs 26.1, Dired+, Windows 10

Suppose I has the next dir tree:

```
myproject
myproject\app\
myproject\app\build
myproject\app\src
myproject\lib\build
myproject\lib\src
myproject\lib2\build
myproject\lib3\build
myproject\lib3\src
```

I want to delete folders **build** in all subfolders. After delete the result must be like this.

```
myproject
myproject\app\
myproject\app\src
myproject\lib\
myproject\lib\src
myproject\lib2\
myproject\lib3\
myproject\lib3\src
```

Is it possible? And is it possible in dired mode?

Answer (score 2):

In Dired:

- You can use **`D`** (command `dired-do-delete`) to delete all marked files and subdirectories in the current Dired listing
- You can use **`M-+ D`** (command `diredp-do-delete-recursive`) to delete all marked files and subdirectories, found recursively. (This one is [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) only).

User option `dired-recursive-deletes` controls whether deletion of
non-empty directories is allowed.

You can also use commands like these, to mark files and subdirectories:

- **`% m`** (`dired-mark-files-regexp`)
- **`M-+ % m`** (`diredp-mark-files-regexp-recursive`)
- **`% g`** (`dired-mark-files-containing`)
- **`M-+ % g`** (`diredp-mark-files-containing-regexp-recursive`)

You can also use various commands in `find-dired.el` and [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/find-dired%2b.el), to list files that satisfy certain conditions, found recursively. (You can then mark some of them and act on the marked ones.)